# .htaccess to PayPal & PayPal Sandbox

Tags: .htaccess

For testing on my pre-live site, I'd like to allow only my own IPs and PayPal Sandbox.

For production, I'd like to allow only PayPal to my IPN listener.

I can restrict in .htaccess to my IPs, but including paypal.com causes 403 in the IPN generator on the SandBox.

I understand this may be a security issue for PayPal, but I'd like it anyway if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing with paypal sandbox, your .htaccess allow should look like follow

```
    Allow from .paypal.com
```

That should allow incomming connection from all machine with *.paypal.com RDNS.

You maybe missing the "dot" before paypal.

---

If using LiteSpeed web server try following

```
    Allow from 173.0.82.126
```

That is IP for ipn.sandbox.paypal.com. Also check your server log and see what IPs are being reject.

Comment: Thank-you for you help.  I tried and sandbox IPN still gives 403.  Is that in LiteSpeed format?

Comment: Lightspeed don't seems to support hostname in htaccess allow. I updated my answer.

Comment: That worked (but Allow should be allow).  That address works for sandbox, but it won't work for production because PayPal is using dynamic IPs.  If it's truly true that litespeed won't allow domains, that add to their crappines.  Know anything about this?  http://serverfault.com/questions/446152/litespeed-enable-access-control-allow-origin-no-response-header-on-cors-request

Comment: Paypal is not using dynamic IPs, but they have multiple server for the same hostname. You can get the list at https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/92 (That link is from https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_golivechecklist Section 5)

Comment: OK, phew.  I must've misread.  I thought they were applying it to the IPN deliverer.

Answer (score 0):

A little update for **Apache 2.4**: the new directive should be:

```
Require host .paypal.com
```

Or, if you need the ip:

```
Require ip 173.0.82.126
```

If you are still using 2.2, IGNORE this and keep using the old syntax, as shown by John Siu's answer.